# Getting to 'Hello, World' with an Orchard Widget

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms

When I first installed Orchard via WebPI, I was pretty happy with it.  However, I wanted to write a "Recent Comments" widget for my blog, and I've been having a devil of a time just getting a "Hello, World" widget working.

I create a module, widget, views, all that, and while the module shows up under the Modules tab, the Widget doesn't show up when I try to add it to the sidebar.

I followed Orchard documentation and Maarten's tutorial: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/01/21/Writing-an-Orchard-widget-LatestTwitter.aspx

Here's my code, what am I missing?: https://gist.github.com/1642453

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is because you are missing the widget content type declaration in your migration. You do register the Content Part correctly, but you never define a widget to use it.

Take a look at the `UpdateFrom1()` method in this documentation page : http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-widget

Comment: And by the way the Maarteen's article does have this code too. You must have missed it somehow.